# Guideness with rendering react-native array of integers individually over time

Tags: arrays, react-native, rendering, state, hook

I'm still **learning** react-native and I'm on a college project that I must make an app that **renders on-screen** the **values of four arrays individually**, four at a time and changing their values to the next one of the array overtime after pressing the start button;

The four of them have the exact same length but don't have a fixed one;

If possible could someone give me some **hints** on how to **manage that**? most examples that I found so far renders the whole array at once.

I thought about setting them in the state and then rendering using their index somehow, then overtime increasing the index pointing to the next value of the array.

Each array should be something like this:

```
"sensor_data_1": { "0": 100, "1": 101, "2": 102, "3": 103, ... }
```

or

```
"sensor_data_1": [ 100, 101, 102, 103, ... ]
```

This is the component on where I was supposed to render

```
const SensorsDetail = ({ evaluation }) => {

  const [state, setState] = useState(evaluation);

  return(
    <View style={styles.view}>
        <Card>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{state.sensor_data_1}</Text>
        </Card>
        <Card>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{state.sensor_data_2}</Text>
        </Card>
        <Card>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{state.sensor_data_3}</Text>
        </Card>
        <Card>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{state.sensor_data_4}</Text>
        </Card>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some hints without giving away the full answer...

1. You should be using the state. You need to store the current "index" that is being rendered. You will probably need 2 state values. 1 for the current array and 1 for the current index. Once the current index reaches the end then you can move onto the next array (and reset the index).
2. You can access array and object values the same `myObject["0"]`. This will get both the first index in an array and the value "0" in an object.
3. You can use setTimeout or setInterval to do something after time. You can lookup the difference, but pretty much setTimeout will just sit for a specified time and then execute something while setInterval will execute something continuously after a set period until the interval is cleared.

If you need more then I can provide a generic example.

Comment: Hey thank you soooooo much! And if you could, I would like a lot if you could give me a generic example so I could visualize better where should I be going.